# want to copy multiple *.txt files from several directories to the same directory but rename the new file

Tags: pax

I have atleast 2-3 *.txt files inside several hundred directories. What I need is: 1. copy the *.txt from every directory to the same directory but by renaming the filename to *_name.txt (* should be the original name of the .txt and the string "name" is same for all newly copied files. Can I use pax for this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use `pax`, but is a pretty straightforward way to get what you need done, done:

```
IFS="\n"
for file in *.txt; do
    cp -- "$file" "${file%.txt}_name.txt"
done
```

The construct `${var%suffix}` will strip `suffix` from the end of the value of `$var`; this is used to remove the file extension.

Comment: Glad to have helped.